# ui element access in JQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery

I use this simple example to forbid access to the second tab. Returning false works fine, but I have to look first, which tab is to be selected. The ui paramter is an object, alert(ui), but I can not use any ui variables or functions. Do I have to cast the object to something?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta  http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>tabs demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="libraries/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:800px;height:600px">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Überblick</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>System</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
        <pre><code>$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh     
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({

        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) { alert( ui.newTab.id ); }
    });
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just disable the tab.

> disable( index )
>
> Disables a tab. The selected tab cannot be disabled. To disable more
>   than one tab at once, set the disabled option: $( "#tabs" ).tabs(
>   "option", "disabled", [ 1, 2, 3 ] ).

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-disable

Making a user belive, he can click a element, which in reallity, he can't is bad UI design!

Comment: I ask for a password to gain access. Just killed it to shorten the code.

Comment: Then you maybe should present the password field in the tab and as soon as the user loogs it, the content is replaced. Just view 'source code' to see the code is a little bit of a massive security hole ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.newTab.find("a").attr("href"));
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Upvoted because you leaded me to solution in my case which was: alert(ui.newTab.attr('id'));  Thanks!